# Where to download python installation exe for windows

Tags: python-3.x

From where can we find the exe installation file to install specific Python version in Windows?

Python [Looking for a specific release?](https://www.python.org/downloads/) has 3.9.15 download link.

[image]

However, there is no exe file for installation as described in the page of 3.9.15.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Manually type the URL e.g. https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3913/ for Python 3.9.13.

Then the page has the download link to the exe file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Python org removed executables from the website, so the upper response will not fit, but executables are still available in their FTP. Please use this for all the versions to download the executable:

https://www.python.org/ftp/python